# Animation lag when showing and hiding an actionbar

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I have a requirement to animate a fragment from being full screen to being a smaller element of the screen as part of a custom navigation drawer.

The problem I am facing is that the actionbar needs to be hosted on the parent activity and not the fragment. To workaround the limitation of not having the actionbar on the fragment I am showing and hiding the actionbar when the animation begins and ends.

I am experiencing a loss in frames where the animation then becomes instant and shows no scaling, if I stop hiding or showing the actionbar and just have it shown the whole time, the animation works fine.

My animation code:

```
private void setUpAnimations() {
    scaleIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_in);
    scaleIn.setFillAfter(true);
    scaleIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            menu.bringToFront();
            isAnimating = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            isAnimating = true;
        }
    });

    scaleOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_out);
    scaleOut.setFillAfter(true);
    scaleOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            isAnimating = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            isAnimating = true;
        }
    });

    menuScaleIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.menu_scale_in);
    menuScaleOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.menu_scale_out);
}

public void scaleIn() {
    isMenuOpen = true;
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    containter.startAnimation(scaleIn);
    menu.startAnimation(menuScaleIn);
}

public void scaleOut() {
    isMenuOpen = false;
    containter.bringToFront();
    containter.startAnimation(scaleOut);
    menu.startAnimation(menuScaleOut);
    getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```

Comment: try to hide `ActionBar` in `onAnimationStart`

Comment: I still get a bit of a weird animation lag using onAnimationStart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't ever really resolve this, instead I put the toolbar on the parent activity and called hide and show from within the fragment via an interface. This certainly isn't the solution but I was working to a deadline.